# when eter param into axieadopt The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

[image]Whenever i pass parameter in adoptAxie function through following error :-

The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.

Please Help me

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;
import "./Pausable.sol";
import "./SafeMath.sol";
import "./HasNoEther.sol";
    
    
    contract AxiePresale is HasNoEther, Pausable {
      using SafeMath for uint256;
    
      // No Axies can be adopted after this end date: Friday, March 16, 2018 11:59:59 PM GMT.
      uint256 constant public PRESALE_END_TIMESTAMP = 1649142348;
    
      uint8 constant public CLASS_BEAST = 0;
      uint8 constant public CLASS_AQUATIC = 2;
      uint8 constant public CLASS_PLANT = 4;
    
      uint256 constant public INITIAL_PRICE_INCREMENT = 1600 szabo; // 0.0016 Ether
      uint256 constant public INITIAL_PRICE = INITIAL_PRICE_INCREMENT;
      uint256 constant public REF_CREDITS_PER_AXIE = 5;
    
      mapping (uint8 => uint256) public currentPrices;
      mapping (uint8 => uint256) public priceIncrements;
    
      mapping (uint8 => uint256) public totalAxiesAdopted;
      mapping (address => mapping (uint8 => uint256)) public axiesAdopted;
    
      mapping (address => uint256) public referralCredits;
      mapping (address => uint256) public axiesRewarded;
      uint256 public totalAxiesRewarded;
    
      event AxiesAdopted(
        address indexed adopter,
        uint8 indexed clazz,
        uint256 quantity,
        address indexed referrer
      );
    
      event AxiesRewarded(address indexed receiver, uint256 quantity);
    
      event AdoptedAxiesRedeemed(address indexed receiver, uint8 indexed clazz, uint256 quantity);
      event RewardedAxiesRedeemed(address indexed receiver, uint256 quantity);
    
      function AxiePresale() public {
        priceIncrements[CLASS_BEAST] = priceIncrements[CLASS_AQUATIC] = priceIncrements[CLASS_PLANT] = INITIAL_PRICE_INCREMENT;
    
        currentPrices[CLASS_BEAST] = currentPrices[CLASS_AQUATIC] = currentPrices[CLASS_PLANT] = INITIAL_PRICE;
      }
    
      function axiesPrice(
        uint256 beastQuantity,
        uint256 aquaticQuantity,
        uint256 plantQuantity
      )
        public
        view
        returns (uint256 totalPrice)
      {
        uint256 price;
    
        (price,,) = _axiesPrice(CLASS_BEAST, beastQuantity);
        totalPrice = totalPrice.add(price);
    
        (price,,) = _axiesPrice(CLASS_AQUATIC, aquaticQuantity);
        totalPrice = totalPrice.add(price);
    
        (price,,) = _axiesPrice(CLASS_PLANT, plantQuantity);
        totalPrice = totalPrice.add(price);
      }
    
      function adoptAxies(
        uint256 beastQuantity,
        uint256 aquaticQuantity,
        uint256 plantQuantity,
        address referrer
      )
        public
        payable
        whenNotPaused
      {
        require(now <= PRESALE_END_TIMESTAMP);
    
        require(beastQuantity <= 3);
        require(aquaticQuantity <= 3);
        require(plantQuantity <= 3);
    
        address adopter = msg.sender;
        address actualReferrer = 0x0;
    
        // An adopter cannot be his/her own referrer.
        if (referrer != adopter) {
          actualReferrer = referrer;
        }
    
        uint256 value = msg.value;
        uint256 price;
    
        if (beastQuantity > 0) {
          price = _adoptAxies(
            adopter,
            CLASS_BEAST,
            beastQuantity,
            actualReferrer
          );
    
          require(value >= price);
          value -= price;
        }
    
        if (aquaticQuantity > 0) {
          price = _adoptAxies(
            adopter,
            CLASS_AQUATIC,
            aquaticQuantity,
            actualReferrer
          );
    
          require(value >= price);
          value -= price;
        }
    
        if (plantQuantity > 0) {
          price = _adoptAxies(
            adopter,
            CLASS_PLANT,
            plantQuantity,
            actualReferrer
          );
    
          require(value >= price);
          value -= price;
        }
    
        msg.sender.transfer(value);
    
        // The current referral is ignored if the referrer's address is 0x0.
        if (actualReferrer != 0x0) {
          uint256 numCredit = referralCredits[actualReferrer]
            .add(beastQuantity)
            .add(aquaticQuantity)
            .add(plantQuantity);
    
          uint256 numReward = numCredit / REF_CREDITS_PER_AXIE;
    
          if (numReward > 0) {
            referralCredits[actualReferrer] = numCredit % REF_CREDITS_PER_AXIE;
            axiesRewarded[actualReferrer] = axiesRewarded[actualReferrer].add(numReward);
            totalAxiesRewarded = totalAxiesRewarded.add(numReward);
            AxiesRewarded(actualReferrer, numReward);
          } else {
            referralCredits[actualReferrer] = numCredit;
          }
        }
      }
    
      function redeemAdoptedAxies(
        address receiver,
        uint256 beastQuantity,
        uint256 aquaticQuantity,
        uint256 plantQuantity
      )
        public
        onlyOwner
        returns (
          uint256 /* remainingBeastQuantity */,
          uint256 /* remainingAquaticQuantity */,
          uint256 /* remainingPlantQuantity */
        )
      {
        return (
          _redeemAdoptedAxies(receiver, CLASS_BEAST, beastQuantity),
          _redeemAdoptedAxies(receiver, CLASS_AQUATIC, aquaticQuantity),
          _redeemAdoptedAxies(receiver, CLASS_PLANT, plantQuantity)
        );
      }
    
      function redeemRewardedAxies(
        address receiver,
        uint256 quantity
      )
        public
        onlyOwner
        returns (uint256 remainingQuantity)
      {
        remainingQuantity = axiesRewarded[receiver] = axiesRewarded[receiver].sub(quantity);
    
        if (quantity > 0) {
          // This requires that rewarded Axies are always included in the total
          // to make sure overflow won't happen.
          totalAxiesRewarded -= quantity;
    
          RewardedAxiesRedeemed(receiver, quantity);
        }
      }
    
      /**
       * @dev Calculate price of Axies from the same class.
       * @param clazz The class of Axies.
       * @param quantity Number of Axies to be calculated.
       */
      function _axiesPrice(
        uint8 clazz,
        uint256 quantity
      )
        private
        view
        returns (uint256 totalPrice, uint256 priceIncrement, uint256 currentPrice)
      {
        priceIncrement = priceIncrements[clazz];
        currentPrice = currentPrices[clazz];
    
        uint256 nextPrice;
    
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
          totalPrice = totalPrice.add(currentPrice);
          nextPrice = currentPrice.add(priceIncrement);
    
          if (nextPrice / 100 finney != currentPrice / 100 finney) {
            priceIncrement >>= 1;
          }
    
          currentPrice = nextPrice;
        }
      }
    
      /**
       * @dev Adopt some Axies from the same class.
       * @param adopter Address of the adopter.
       * @param clazz The class of adopted Axies.
       * @param quantity Number of Axies to be adopted, this should be positive.
       * @param referrer Address of the referrer.
       */
      function _adoptAxies(
        address adopter,
        uint8 clazz,
        uint256 quantity,
        address referrer
      )
        private
        returns (uint256 totalPrice)
      {
        (totalPrice, priceIncrements[clazz], currentPrices[clazz]) = _axiesPrice(clazz, quantity);
    
        axiesAdopted[adopter][clazz] = axiesAdopted[adopter][clazz].add(quantity);
        totalAxiesAdopted[clazz] = totalAxiesAdopted[clazz].add(quantity);
    
        AxiesAdopted(
          adopter,
          clazz,
          quantity,
          referrer
        );
      }
    
      /**
       * @dev Redeem adopted Axies from the same class.
       * @param receiver Address of the receiver.
       * @param clazz The class of adopted Axies.
       * @param quantity Number of adopted Axies to be redeemed.
       */
      function _redeemAdoptedAxies(
        address receiver,
        uint8 clazz,
        uint256 quantity
      )
        private
        returns (uint256 remainingQuantity)
      {
        remainingQuantity = axiesAdopted[receiver][clazz] = axiesAdopted[receiver][clazz].sub(quantity);
    
        if (quantity > 0) {
          // This requires that adopted Axies are always included in the total
          // to make sure overflow won't happen.
          totalAxiesAdopted[clazz] -= quantity;
    
          AdoptedAxiesRedeemed(receiver, clazz, quantity);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: can you edit the contract code so that it can compile? there are escapes before `[` and some other mistakes as well

Comment: * and the imported files as well

Comment: sytax is correct no error on compilation at time of deploy adopt axie param thrugh error as i put screenshot on above

Comment: how can this code snippet compile? there are escape chars around brackets and there is array access at the and? check your code snippet, it's impossible

Comment: please suggest where is mistake

Comment: the code snippet is still uncompilable. i'm going to edit the question.